# How to create a Slider in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want the progress bar that look like this, I found some bootstrap progress bar but their is no customized values

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's called `range` ... check here 1 min on google http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's actually an HTML element for this!

```js
$('#myRange').mousemove(function(){
    $('#rangeValue').text($('#myRange').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="1" max="100">
<div id="rangeValue">1</div>
```